# How is a integer mapped to 4 bytes? How to convert 4 bytes into integer in python

Tags: python

I am sending two integers from Java client to Python server.

How is an integer mapped into a 4 integers from 0-255?

How do I convert those 4 bytes back to integer??

Java:

```java
Socket socket = ((host,port));
//converting intArray to byteArray

int[] intArray = {900, 1200};
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = byteBuffer.allocate(intArray.length*4);
IntBuffer intBuffer = byteBuffer.asIntBuffer();
intBuffer.put(intArray);
byte[] byteArray = byteBuffer.array();


//Sending byteArray via socket to python Server

DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
dos.write(byteArray);
```

Python:

```py
#receiving byteArray from Java

imageDimension = clientsocket.recv(1024)
print(imageDimension)
list = list(imageDimension)
print(list)
```

```
output:
b'\x00\x00\x03\x84\x00\x00\x04\xb0'
[0, 0, 3, 132, 0, 0, 4, 176]
```

In this case, it looks like integer 900 is somehow mapped into `[0,0,3,132]`. What is going on here? how are they converting 900 to 4 bytes?

How do I convert `[0,0,3,132]` and `[0,0,4,176]` back to 900 and 1200 in python??

Comment: You should learn about big endian and little endian. Hint: 3*256+132=900

Comment: Now I got it. Yeah I need to learn about those. Thank you.

Comment: See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#order()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In binary, 3 and 132 are `00000011` and `10000100` respectively. 900 in binary is `1110000100`. By concatenating the binary representations of 3 and 132, you get 900.

```
00000011
+       10000100
================
0000001110000100
```

You can use [`struct.unpack`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/struct.html#struct.unpack) to convert bytes into other types.

```
>>> import struct
>>> x = b'\x00\x00\x03\x84\x00\x00\x04\xb0'
>>> struct.unpack(">II", x)
(900, 1200)
```

The `">II"` [format string](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/struct.html#format-strings) indicates that the eight-byte `bytes` object should be interpreted as two four-byte integers with little-endian byte ordering.